# How to use Plupload in themes

Tags: theme-development, plupload

I am developing a theme which needs uploading from front-end. I want to integrate plupload in my theme while keeping in mind that:

- Uploading will be handled upon form submission, and not from the plupload regular method.
  This means that I just need the design of plupload, and not the uploading functionality. After selecting the files, when I submit the form (containing selected files and other information), I should be able to grab all the form info (including files info) in the target page.
  E.g. In user profile page, I want to update my avatar along with my other information.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Take a look at the source here](https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box/blob/master/inc/fields/plupload-image.php).

Comment: @kaiser, I am also looking for the same solution. Can you explain more? Or should I open another question?

Answer (score 1):

Plupload can fall back to HTML4 (form submission) file uploads. Just define the runtime to be HTML4 in the js runtime parameters.

I know the following plugin is using Plupload so I would probably just look at their source. Do not copy but I would use it to help get yourself going. http://www.tn3gallery.com/